# create and display multiple windows simultaneously using javaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-8, finalcut

I'm currently designing a GUI using JavaFX and SceneBulder.

I would like it be composed of several windows, each of which can be hidden, resized, deleted, etc.... in much the same way that is posible in Final Cut Pro 7.

For example: http://www.squarebox.com/legacy/xfer_fcp7.png

I have read various posts and articles (e.g. Angela Caicedo's article for Oracle) about creating apps with multiple windows but none of them seem to address displaying several windows simultaneously and enabling the contents of these separate windows to communicate with each other.

I have read a post which suggests just creating several stages (and therefore windows) in the start method of the main Class. I am tempted to go down this route but am suspicious as it seems crude and I get the sense that this might lead to problems later down the line with regards to getting each window to interact.

Any help or recommendations with regards to design would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You might look at using an MVC and several JFrame's, were currently doing a similar project where we have multiple managers and each calls a disposable window to display a chart when the user asks for it.

Comment: This company offers a MDI framework for javaFX. see http://blog.sibvisions.com/2015/11/. It's open source: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sibvisions.jvx/jvxfx